# How to control the execute sequence of event handler with EventAggregator in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

I'm using Prism EventAggregator in my app. In my scenario, it's a download module, when download completion, publish the event. Four ViewModels subscribe this event and have their own event handler, some for writing log file, some for updating user interface.

- How to control these event handlers execution sequence?
- Are there executing in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, they execute on the same thread that the event was published. If you are specifying a thread (UI / Worker), then they *may* execute in parallel.

Invocation of the event handlers is generally the order in which they subscribed, but I wouldn't depend on this behavior.

Why do you care about the order? Is it because you have many phases of initialization? Send out a seperate message for each phase.

Comment: After the download completed, I use aggregator.GetEvent<>().Publish() to publish the vent, in the four viewmodels' constructor, I use aggregator.GetEvent<>().Subscribe() to subscribe the event. Do you mean, the execution sequence depends on which constructor of the four viewmodels execute? Or I'm using it in a wrong way?

Comment: the order of handler execution depends on the chronological order in which the `Subscribe()` method was called.

Comment: If you are using Prism 2.0 it calls the subscribers in reverse order http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/3738